# Double free or corruption (!prev) with one malloc() and one free() in a loop

Tags: c, free

I'm practicing C by coding functions of the string.h lib. But I'm currently stuck with a problem that I don't understand. When I execute my program, it crashes with the following message:

> double free or corruption (!prev)

I tried with Valgrind but it seems that the bug does not occur with it.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char * duplicateString(const char * str) {
    size_t strLength = strlen(str);

    char * duplicatedString = malloc(strLength);
    if(duplicatedString == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    // +1 to copy '\0'
    strncpy(duplicatedString, str, strLength + 1);

    return duplicatedString;
}

void test_duplicateString()
{
  const char * src = "abc";
  char buf[1024];
  int i, j;
  char * temp = duplicateString(src);

  assert((strcmp((src),(temp)) == 0));
  assert(src != temp);
  free(temp);

  for(i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < i; ++j)
      buf[j] = (char) ('a' + (j % 26));
    buf[i] = '\0';

    temp = duplicateString(buf);
    assert((strcmp((buf),(temp)) == 0));
    free(temp);
  }
}

int main()
{
    test_duplicateString();
    return 0;
}
```

According to GDB, this error happens always at line 38 when i=136.
For example why at i=136, and not before?

```
#0  0x00007ffff7a6a5f8 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007ffff7a6ba7a in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007ffff7aa905a in __libc_message () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007ffff7aae9a6 in malloc_printerr () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ffff7aaf18e in _int_free () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x000000000040093e in test_duplicateString () at /media/sf_data/Cours/Polytech/DI3/Langage_C/DoubleFreeTest/main.c:38
        src = 0x400a10 "abc"
        buf = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef\000\344\377\367\377\177\000\000\240\345\377\377\377\177\000\000x\030\375\367\377\177\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\230\331\377\367\377\177\000\000`\346\377\377\377\177\000\000?M\336\367\377\177\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"...
        i = 136
        j = 136
        temp = 0x602010 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef"
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "test_duplicateString"
#6  0x0000000000400979 in main () at /media/sf_data/Cours/Polytech/DI3/Langage_C/DoubleFreeTest/main.c:44
No locals.
```

Comment: `char * duplicatedString = malloc(strLength);` should be `char * duplicatedString = malloc(strLength+1);`

Comment: `malloc(strLength` **`+1`** `)`

Comment: `char * duplicatedString = malloc(strLength);`. Shouldn't that be `malloc(strLength + 1)`?

Comment: And I find it surprising that you say valgrind doesn't spot the error. It certainly does for me: `==8066== Invalid write of size 1; at 0x402D763: strncpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so); by 0x8048745: test_duplicateString (in /tmp/a.out)`

Comment: Note: Simplification `strncpy(duplicatedString, str, strLength + 1); return duplicatedString;` --> `return memcpy(duplicatedString, str, strLength + 1);`

Comment: @AlanAu: Oh yes, I guess I should learn how to use valgrind.

Comment: @chux : Thanks for the tip. I'm rewriting the string library for a C training course. But I'm not sure I'm allowed to use memcpy() since I had to write strncpy(). It is clever but too easy.

Comment: @AlanAu: I remember now, I was looking for the message "double free or corruption (!prev)" in Valgrind  but it does not appear, that why I supposed that the program has worked though I had the "invalid write of .." message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put what all of the comments said into an answer, in your function `duplicateString()`, you didn't allocate enough memory to fit the string *and* the null character.

So when you do this

```
strncpy(duplicatedString, str, strLength + 1);
```

You're copying more than the buffer can hold. The solution is obviously to increase the buffer size by 1.

```
char * duplicatedString = malloc(strLength + 1);
```

Comment: Oh yes indeed. It works, of course now it looks like a beginner's mistake. But now I've a more interesting question. There is something that I don't understand. Since I didn't allocate enough blocks, how can free() triggers an error? Is it not supposed to free only the allocated blocks? I can understand why the fact to set a number outside an array can not crash a program but, this not.

Comment: @MrG0z I'm not sure of the specifics (I don't know all the intricacies of `malloc`), but it's probably because `malloc` allocated more memory than requested, and used that extra memory for some sort of bookkeeping. When you called `free`, this bookkeeping data was read, and it was determined that the memory had been corrupted (you wrote over it).